# Type matches correctly, but why " #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint" keeps poping out?

Tags: sql

This is my first table "address".

```
create table address(
street varchar(32) not null,
city varchar(32) not null,
state varchar(32) not null,
zip_code varchar(32) not null,
primary key(zip_code)
)
```

This is my second table "customer".

```
create table customer(
customer_id integer not null,
name varchar(32) not null,
primary key(customer_id)
)
```

This is my relational table about above two tables. But why cannot I make it? The type matches well. So please.

```
create table cus_live(
customer_id integer not null,
zip_code varchar(32) not null,
primary key(customer_id, zip_code),
foreign key(customer_id) references customer,
foreign key(zip_code) references address
)
```

Comment: I don't believe you're telling sql what columns of "address" and "customer" are being referenced in the foreign key.

Comment: Why is zipcode the primary key in your address table? What if two customers have addresses having the same zip code? How would the FK constraint know which address belongs to which customer? I would suggest adding an address id column and using that as your primary key for the address table.

Comment: Could you say more clearly, i cannot understand you. Thx. I new at sql.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks for "zip_code" thing~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way to create a foreign key constraint:

```
create table cus_live(
    cus_live_id int not null,
    customer_id int not null,
    address_id int not null,
    primary key(cus_live_id),
    foreign key(customer_id) references customer (customer_id),
    foreign key(address_id) references address (address_id)
)
```

Notice the changes I made:

- After `references [tableName]`, added the key name in parentheses. This will tell SQL which column is referenced in the foreign key constrant.
- Changed the primary key of the table to its own unique id rather than a composite of two columns. Usually this is better practice.
- Changed primary key of address table to address_id instead of zipcode. Otherwise you would have conflicts if two customers have the same zipcode but different addresses within that zipcode.
- Made your id's integers instead of strings.

Also, note that this is all assuming that cus_live has some other columns that you have excluded (and cannot be included on either the address or customer table) and hence warrants having this third table in the first place. Otherwise you could just put address_id on the customer table like this:

```
create table address(
    address_id int not null,
    street varchar(32) not null,
    city varchar(32) not null,
    state varchar(32) not null,
    zip_code varchar(32) not null,
    primary key(address_id)
)

create table customer(
    customer_id int not null,
    name varchar(32) not null,
    address_id int not null,
    primary key(customer_id)
    foreign key(address_id) references address (address_id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I refined my address table and cus_live table, using address_id instead of zip_code. It worked~~ Thanks!!

Comment: @Sherry: note that `foreign key(customer_id) references customer` is valid *standard* SQL. It's just that MySQL doesn't support this.